# Meaning of "up" in "clean up after yourself"

Tags: adverbs

What does the adverb *up* in the idiom:

> Clean **up** after yourself.

mean ?

Comment: Best google such expressions before asking as most answers are found online ; https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/clean+up

Comment: The expression "clean after yourself" doesn't make sense, even though *clean* is a synonym of *clean up*. This is the reason that had me wondering over the meaning of the adverb *up* in the context above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase [*clean up after*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clean%20up%20after) itself means:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : to make a place clean after it has been left dirty or messy by (someone)
>   // His mother is always *cleaning up after* him.
>   // You should learn to *clean up after* yourself.

---

The use of *up* can be used as an intensifier—and it's defined as an adverb in this sense:

> **6 b** —used as an intensifier
>   // clean *up* the house

So, you can simply *clean the house* or you can *clean **up** the house*. The former is just the general action of cleaning, while the latter specifically means to remove visible dirt and grime (or disorder).

---

However, the use of *up* in the *idiom* likely comes from the following type of usage:

> Pick **up** garbage.

So, by extrapolation, it could be a shortened version of something like:

> Clean **up** your mess after you made it yourself.
>   → Clean up after yourself.

---

There are related phrases that have the same general meaning.

[*Pick up after (someone)*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pick%20up%20after):

> : to clean the mess created by (someone)
>   // You have to *pick up after* yourself if you make a mess.
>   // His mother still *picks up after* him.

[*Tidy up after (someone)*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tidy%20up%20after):

> : to clean up someone else's messes
>   // I'm tired of always *tidying up after* you.

In both cases, it could be a figurative interpretation of literally picking something *up* and then disposing of it or putting it into proper order.

With the uses of *pick up* and *tidy up*, *clean up* probably followed suit—assuming it didn't simply come about along with the others.

---

Note that there is one last meaning of [*clean up*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clean%20up) that doesn't involve ***after*** *yourself*, but might still be related in some respects:

> 2 : to become free of drug or alcohol addiction
>   // I always *cleaned up* for tours. … By the end of the tour, I'm perfectly clean and should have stayed sober.
>   — Keith Richards

The same expression can also be used in other ways—to mean *get your act together*, in a sentence like the following (which is my own):

> You look awful. You really need to *clean yourself up*.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Clean up" is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/clean+up). The whole phrase is saying something like "Do not make a mess" or "leave this room clean when you are finished with what you are doing."